# Why binding do not work for target to source

Tags: wpf, mvvm, rotation, rotatetransform, updatesourcetrigger

I have a canvas which has many images appearing dynamically on it and i used items control for it. I had to drag drop and rotate(on mouse right button click) those images and update new locations and rotation angle back 
to source code (VM and Model).

I am able to display on my screen images and my canvas.left and canvas.right are getting updated for new locations in source when i do drag and drop of Images on canvas.
The problem is when i rotate image, The image gets rotated but the new Angle in source is not updated in my source (VModel), I mean this property never gets called when i rotate the image.

```
 public double Angle {
            get { return angle; }
            set  //NEVER GETS CALLED ON ROTATION
            {
                angle = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Angle");
            }
        }
```

It is binded correctly because when i display the images dynamically on canvas, they are displayed with the same angle which i have provided them from source. Earlier i suspected  Mode to not set of
TwoWay binding. Even i set to TwoWay it do not work. I also added UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged but still do not work . Why angle is never updated on rotating the image whereas canvas.left and canvas.top
are updated.

Here is my XAML :

```
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <dd:DragCanvas Height="800" Width="1000" Background="Black" x:Name="dragCanvas" 
                         AllowDragging="True" 
                         />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=path}" >
                        </Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=Canvas_Left , Mode=TwoWay}" />  //It is updated
                        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Canvas_Top , Mode=TwoWay}" /> //It is Updated
                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">  //It never updated from target to source but source to target is updated
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Path=Angle ,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>                                
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Here is where i rotate on mouse right button click(inside dd:DragCanvas )

```
   public class DragCanvas : Canvas
    {

       protected override void OnMouseRightButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)  //HERE IS WHERE I ROTATE by 90 degree
        {
            base.OnMouseRightButtonUp(e);
            ElementBeingDragged = e.Source as UIElement;
            var rotateTransform = ElementBeingDragged.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
            if (rotateTransform == null)
            {
                rotateTransform = new RotateTransform();
                ElementBeingDragged.RenderTransform = rotateTransform;
                ElementBeingDragged.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);
            }
            rotateTransform.Angle += 90;
            ElementBeingDragged.UpdateLayout();
        }
    }
```

How to update angle property (target to source), such that each time i rotate the Image i have set part of the property Angle called

```
public double Angle {
            get { return angle; }
            set  //It must be called when i rotate the image on right mouse click
            {
                angle = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Angle");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you saying that `RotateTransform.Angle` never updates your viewmodel `Angle` property?

Comment: By the way, you're setting traps for yourself by making your backing fields public and not prefixing them with underscores. With the help of intellisense, one day you'll end up assigning a value to `canvas_Top` and wondering why `PropertyChanged` is never raised.

Comment: You're binding to `LayoutTransform` but updating `RenderTransform`. `LayoutTransform` gets applied while calculating Layout, while `RenderTransform` gets applied at the time of rendering.

Comment: As a note, you don't have to call `ElementBeingDragged.UpdateLayout()`. That's entirely redundant.

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes he means same .

Comment: @EdPlunkett yes you are right.  My rotation done on mouse right button click actually rotates the image but do not update the Angle in VM. Whereas while loading the images in canvas, the images are displayed at the angle which i provided by source, so that means source-> target binding is working but not vise versa

Comment: @Clemens Its noted, I am still not able to make it, Could you please help me ?

Comment: Are you sure your OnMouseRightButtonUp method is ever called? It is an overridden method of the Canvas, but should probably be an event handler on the ContentPresenter (which you could also set in XAML by an EventSetter).

Comment: @Clemens yes it being called.

Comment: And did you check if `e.Source` is actually a ContentPresenter where you have set the RenderTransform in XAML? `if (rotateTransform == null)` should then always be false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're binding to `LayoutTransform` but updating `RenderTransform`. `LayoutTransform` gets applied while calculating Layout, while `RenderTransform` gets applied at the time of rendering.

Change your binding to `RenderTransform` and it should work.

**Edit :** Just realized when switching to using `RenderTransform`, you need to apply the transform to the Image, not the `ContentPresenter` wrapping the image.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Image Source="{Binding Path=path}" >
            <Image.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Path=Angle ,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>                                
            </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=Canvas_Left , Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Canvas_Top , Mode=TwoWay}" />                       
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

If you apply a transformation during the Layout pass, it will adjust other items within the Layout to fit as well. So applying a transform to the `ContentPresenter` that wraps the `Image` during Layout will also calculate that it needs to apply the same transform to the inside `Image`.

But if it's applied during Rendering, the only the `ContentPresenter` gets the transform applied and the child `Image` remains unchanged because the initial Layout pass decided it didn't need any modifications.

Comment: but stuckstuck is also saying that his binding works oneway (mode). He says that when the first time he launch the application he has image displayed on canvas with the same angle which he has provided through source. Do you think that ninding with LayoutTransform  will work on source to target but not target to source ?

Comment: @Rachel You mean " <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">" this should be " <Setter Property="RenderTransform ">" ? But then why it works in the case when i provide angle from source to target. It display the images on the angles which are provided by source but when i rotate the images it do not update back to VM about angle change.

Comment: @stuckstuck Both properties work to transform the angle of the object, however they have different timing. For example, if you place text in a StackPanel that resizes to fit it's child, it will display like normal. If you apply a LayoutTransform to draw the text vertically, it will also change the size of the StackPanel surrounding it to match the vertical text. But if you use a RenderTransform, the StackPanel will get drawn as normal assuming horizontal text, however the Text itself will get drawn vertically (and outside the bounds of the StackPanel).

Comment: @stuckstuck But in your case, you are are using two separate properties. During Layout calculations and for initial display, it is using the bound value. But during rendering, it is using a user-applied value. Change your binding to use RenderTransform and it should work as you expect.

Comment: @Rachel Thanks .. i am outside at the moment, i would apply your solution tomorrow and will mark you as answer as soon it works. Otherwise will disturb you again :)

Comment: @Rachel It worked when i placed my Angle binding inside the Image in DataTemplate. But why it worked that i still do not understand, Could you please modify your answer suggesting me to use "RenderTransorm" and giving me the reason that why it worked when i placed the same code in Image (In Data Template) instead of <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle> ? So that i mark you as answer

Comment: <DataTemplate>
                                <Image Source="{Binding Path=path}">
                                    <Image.RenderTransform >
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Path=Angle , Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                                    </Image.RenderTransform>
                                </Image>
                            </DataTemplate>

Comment: @stuckstuck It doesn't work the same because of the example I gave above with StackPanel and Text. The `ItemsContainerPresenter` affects the `ContentPresenter` that wraps the image. If you apply the transform on Layout, it will correctly know to apply the transform to child objects too when doing the layout pass. But if you apply it on Render, then only the `ContentPresenter` gets altered during rendering, and not it's child object.

Comment: @KellyElton So debug and fix it? Answers on here are meant to explain the issue, and often provide a code example to help explain. The primary purpose of answers isn't to give you the code, even though a lot of answers on the site do have code that can be copy/pasted with no understanding :)

Comment: @Rachel I could rewrite this whole thing for you to make it actually sensible, but why should I be responsible for your sloppiness?